# Limit absolute positioned element to container width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DZQtt/1/)

I've got some absolute positioned element, that is something like drop-down menu. It should be below its 'ITEM' but when window gets narrow, it has no enought space.

My point is:

-right edge of dropdown should not overflow of its container. Dropdown should have something like `max-right: 0;`

-should be cross-browser

-would be great to avoid js, if its impossible then js should be as simple and fast as possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the problem ? Please show us some code :-)

Comment: For now I've not tried to implement it as I would love to make it with css but I have no real idea how it could be done. When it comes to JS only solution it should not be that hard.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `width` of the absolute child to `100%` and make the parent relatively positioned.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DZQtt/2/

```
li {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
.b {
    ...
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: sub menu should have some width if its possible. For example 200px but no more than container

Comment: the key to this is the setting of `position` of the parent. without it, the `100%` width will be relative to the document.

Comment: @Kluska000 then it would be `width:100%; min-width:200px; 
max-width:100%;`. the `width` component is because IE7 and back have issues with `min-width` and `max-width`, so for those guys it would fallback to `100%` of the container.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DZQtt/3/  ps. I may not care about IE7, maybe even IE8  ps2. I want to say sub menu will be almost always wider than its <li> so that is not correct for this IMO

Comment: @Kluska000 if your submenu item is wider than its `li`, then `100%` is not the way to go. Make it `300%` or something.

Comment: I dont get that point. Content of .b is not visible. .b must have some min-width like 200px but no more than content and must be stick to right edge of container if there is no more place to avoid overflow.

@PlantTheIdea it would cause overflowing and too big width and also it will not avoid overflow on right edge of container.

Comment: 'must stick to right edge of container' ... i think you mean the container's container. the container for `b` is the `li`, whereas it seems you are talking about setting the width based on the `right` position of the `ul`? is this correct?

Comment: I've just got wide sub menu and I dont want it to go outside of user screen. Thats totally everything. And also I need it to stay wide if possible.